# Select value from first table through two other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have my first table `Item` look like this

```
IDItem   ItemName
 559       HEA600
 the IDItem is the primary Key
```

and my second table `ItemQuantity` look like this

```
IDItemQty    IDItem
  9           559
the IDItemQty is the primary Key
the IDItem is the foreign Key
```

and my third table `OrderDetails`

```
IDItemQty     IDOrder
 9              1
 the IDItemQty is the foreign Key
 the IDOrder is the foreign Key
```

i want to select 9 from `OrderDetails` get as result `HEA600` is that possible,i hope i am clear ,thanks in advance

Comment: That is a simple join. Please take a SQL tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by joining tables.

```
SELECT i.ItemName
       od.IDOrder
FROM   orderdetails od 
       INNER JOIN itemquantity iq 
               ON iq.iditemqty = od.iditemqty 
       INNER JOIN item i 
               ON i.iditem = iq.iditem 
WHERE  od.iditemqty = '9'
```

Comment: when i try to do this :SELECT [Name_Item]
      ,[ID_Order]

 FROM [dbo].[OrderDetails]
       INNER JOIN itemquantity iq 
               ON iq.ID_ItemQte = od.ID_ItemQty 
       INNER JOIN item i 
               ON i.ID_Item = iq.ID_Item                                                                                               i get error The multi-part identifier "od.ID_ItemQty" could not be bound

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah, try it now.

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah. The reason your query isn't working is because you're missing an alias. You refer to a table called "od" but then you never define it. You can see the od needs to come after dbo.OrderDetails

Answer (score 1):

Do the simple *join*

```
select i.IDItem, i.ItemName
from Item i 
inner join ItemQuantity iq on iq.IDItem = i.IDItem
inner join OrderDetails od on od.IDOrder = iq.IDOrder
where od.IDItemQty = 9;
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but i want to select data from OrderDetails because there is other columns i want to show it , i try to do this :SELECT [Name_Item]
      ,[ID_Order]

 FROM [dbo].[OrderDetails]
       INNER JOIN itemquantity iq 
               ON iq.ID_ItemQte = od.ID_ItemQty 
       INNER JOIN item i 
               ON i.ID_Item = iq.ID_Item                                                                                               i get error The multi-part identifier "od.ID_ItemQty" could not be bound

Comment: @M.Bouabdallah. The reason your query isn't working is because you're missing an alias. You refer to a table called "od" but then you never define it. You can see the od needs to come after dbo.OrderDetails